# How to pass application userName and password from jenkins to maven

Tags: java, maven, jenkins, parameters, maven-surefire-plugin

In my current Automation framework(Cucumber+Java+Selenium+Maven), I am reading userName and Password from the csv file. But I felt maintenance is it bit difficult. So I am searching solution if can able to pass the userName and password from the Jenkins.

Kindly help me.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the server you try to reach. If the plugin you need username/password for is using the servers sectio of the settings.xml you can add them there [and encrypt them](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-encryption.html).

If username/password are used within you application or tests you can pass them as properties to maven (`-D"propname=propvalue"`) and refer to them in the pom.xml file with `${propname}` - not that the surefire and failsafe plugin might fork new JVMs. So you may need to pass them along in the plugin configuration.

If all fails you can always set environment variables and refer to them via `${env.ENV_VAR_NAME}` in your pom.xml files.

There is a [guide at sonatype about properties](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/resource-filtering-sect-properties.html). (older but still applies)